# Изменений содержимого окна по кнопкам

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, controls

Здравствуйте. Необходимо разделить форму на 3 части. В первой части будет своё содержимой, в других частях своё. Эти части будут переключаться кнопками.
Т.е. при нажатие на первую кнопку, у нас показываются в форме одни объекты, нажимаем на другое, и содержимой всей формы меняется снова. 
Как данный вопрос можно решить? Приблизительно всё будет выглядеть, как на рисунке.
[image: Форма с меню в виде кнопок]

Comment: [`TabControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, сам не додумался)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое Через TabControll. Этот контролл есть и в WinForms и в WPF.
В TabPage добавляйте то что нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Это мне и нужно)

Answer (score 0):

Как альтернативный вариант, можно добавить на форму все необходимые компоненты в скрытом состоянии, а потом кнопкой(как собственно хотите) управлять их видимость.

Но вариант ,@Сергей ,мне кажется, более верный.

Comment: Тоже думал со скрытым состоянием сделать, но по сути `TabControl` намного лучшее будет

Comment: Можно даже сгруппировать в groupbox отдельные группы элементов. И это неплохой вариант, если элементов не много. Иначе же, на winforms даже скрытые элементы в проекте отображаются и рано или поздно начнут налезать друг на друга.  Для нормальной работы придется кидать скрытые группы за пределы формы, что бы они не загораживали видимые, потом менять `Location`. В wpf конечно все проще.

Comment: По сути в WPF не сильно сложнее конструкции все, а возможностей больше, но как-то решил не выходить за зоны комфорта, но надо и там начинать осваиваться. Необходимо в будущем изменить дизайн самого окошка, чтобы не был стандартным и вписывался в общий дизайн и в WPF это возможно, как я понял